elementor/frontend/after_enqueue_styles not working for insert font
I want to add a custom font to Elementor using css
i use this code in fonr.css
@font-face{
    font-family: Estedad;
    font-display:swap;
    src:url(font/Estedad/Estedad-Thin.eot);
    src:url("font/Estedad/Estedad-Thin.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"),
url(font/Estedad/Estedad-Thin.woff2) format("woff2"),
url(font/Estedad/Estedad-Thin.woff) format("woff"),
url(font/Estedad/Estedad-Thin.ttf) format("truetype");
    font-weight:100;
    font-style:normal
}

and in use this code in plugin.php
public function stylesheet()
    {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'elementor-font',plugins_url( 'assets/css/font.css',  __FILE__ ) );
    }
add_action('elementor/frontend/after_enqueue_styles', [ $this,  'stylesheet']);


Have you tried to give an element the font-family: Estedad; in css?
just by adding the @font-face you can not achive any change.
Also please clarify the question; we don't know that you are trying to use the custom font through the typography control of elementor or through custom css.
